# Create multiple files from a template referencing a single txt file and touch

Tags: command-line, bash, ubuntu-touch

I've used `touch` for single creation of blank files and multiple blank files from a list using `cat foo.txt | xargs touch` plus I ran across [How to create multiple files with the Terminal?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605558/how-to-create-multiple-files-with-the-terminal) but I'm having issues figuring out how I can implement the creation of files that use a template from a list of files with pure bash.

File names in foo.txt file:

```
cpt-one.php
cpt-two.php
cpt-three.php
```

template.txt:

```
// lots of code
```

Is there a way I can use `touch` to create the file's from the list using what's in template.txt instead of creating a blank file?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? create multiple exact copies of `template.txt` with their names taken from `foo.txt`?

Comment: Yes that is correct.  Wondered how to properly word that

Answer (score 4):

A `bash`-esque way to do it (without an explicit loop) might be

- read the filenames into a shell array variable

  ```
  mapfile -t files < foo.txt
  ```

  or its synonym `readarray -t files < foo.txt`
- expand the array inside a `tee` command

  ```
  tee < template.txt -- "${files[@]}" > /dev/null
  ```

[The `> /dev/null` is optional - it just hides `tee`'s default standard output from the terminal.]

Comment: +1 for pure bash, makes a pretty golfable code, though it will probably needs to be mentioned that this is bash only approach, probably ksh doesn't have that, but don't quote me. zsh might, but i am not familiar with it

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have thousands of files that you need to create, you can use brace expansion:

```
$> touch cpt-{one,two,three}.php
$> ls
cpt-one.php  cpt-three.php  cpt-two.php
```

Since your objective is to clone template , use `tee` to redirect stdin to multiple files. `tee` writes to both file and stdout, so you will see it echoed  on the terminal

```
$> cat template.txt  | tee cpt-{one,two,three}.php                             
I'm template
```

Alternatively , one could use `while read` structure.  with shell redirection.

```
$> rm *
$> vi inputFile.txt
$> while read FILE; do touch "$FILE" ; done < inputFile.txt
$> ls
cpt-one  cpt-three  cpt-two  inputFile.txt
```

Note well, that this is a simple example, that assumes entries in the file contain no special chars

Now, since you actually want to copy single file in to multiple, you can use the same structure, to `cp /path/to/template "$FILE"`

```
$> ls
inputFile.txt  template.txt
$> cat template.txt                                                            
I'm template
$> while read FILE; do cp template.txt "$FILE" ; done < inputFile.txt            
$> cat cpt-one.php                                                             
I'm template
$>
```