# How to create multiple files (with different names) in a specific directory all at once in a Linux terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My current directory structure

```
├── index.html
├── src
│   └── App.js
└── README.md
```

Now, I wanted to create files `App.js`, `Body.js` and `Footer.js` in a new directory named `components`. So, my final structure will be:

```
├── index.html
├── src
│   ├── App.js
│   └── components
│       ├── Header.js
│       ├── Body.js
│       └── Footer.js
└── README.md
```

I tried something like this:

```
mkdir -p src/components && touch $_/Header.js
touch src/components/Body.js  src/components/Footer.js
```

From [reference](https://askubuntu.com/questions/605558/how-to-create-multiple-files-with-the-terminal), I know to create multiple files at once, we can use

```
touch newfilename{1..N}
```

But, my filenames are having different names.

Is there a way to create all these files in a new directory using a single command with terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can create multiple files with different names in a single command using terminal. Here's an example command that does exactly what you want:

```
mkdir -p src/components && touch src/components/{Header,Body,Footer}.js
```

This command first creates the components directory inside the src directory using `mkdir -p src/components`. Then, it uses the `touch` command to create the Header.js, Body.js, and Footer.js files inside the components directory. The `{Header,Body,Footer}` is brace expansion, which allows you to create multiple file names with a single pattern.

Answer (score 2):

Brace expansion is done by the shell, nothing to do with touch itself. So the fact that your files have different names doesn't matter. ie This will also work:

```
mkdir -p src/components && touch src/components/Header.js src/components/Body.js src/components/Footer.js
```

But obviously it makes sense to use the brace expansion when you can. My point is that this will still work even if the files have totally different names:

```
touch a b c d
```